# Как загрузить fb2 файл?

Tags: xml, objective-c, fb2

Прошу указать путь, что и где искать, делать.

Нужно в `UIWebView` загрузить fb2 файл. Делаю таким образом:

```
NSString *testXMLString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Book" ofType:@"fb2"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error]; 
[web loadHTMLString:testXMLString baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
```

Все вроде ничего, но картинки, что в:

```
<binary id="_4.jpg" content-type="image/jpeg">/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/ ... </binary>
```

не подгружаются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте регуляркой или еще как привести в тексте `<binary..content-type="image/jpeg">/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/...</binary>` к виду `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/..."/>`

Comment: Veliant можно так сказать в ручную перегонять файл не особо хочется. Может есть какой-то другой путь?

Comment: не хотите на objective-c мучать разметку - добавьте в конец testXMLString код на javascript, который будет получать все элементы binary, и заменять их на img с соответствующим src.